# PCD visualization in Rviz [closed]

Tags: rviz, pcl, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Community!

I'm trying to import and manipulate a PCD file in C++ code then visualize the results in Rviz. I feel like this is an easy problem to solve with a couple lines of code but I can't seem to figure them out. I have successfully connected Rviz to my Kinect and Lidar devices and then use PCL etc. to manipulate the live point messages. But I can't seem to import anything and visualize successfully. Any suggestions??

**EDIT:**
Figured it out! heres the code. it might be a bit inefficient but it works.

```
# include <iostream>
# include <string>

#include <ros/ros.h>

#include <pcl_ros/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
#include <pcl_ros/io/pcd_io.h>

typedef pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> PointCloud;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  double x_cloud; double y_cloud; double z_cloud;
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
  ros::init (argc, argv, "my_pcl_tutorial");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<PointCloud> ("points2", 1);
  pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZ> ("yourfile.pcd", *cloud);

  PointCloud::Ptr msg (new PointCloud);
  msg->header.frame_id = "frame1";
  msg->height = cloud->height;
  msg->width = cloud->width;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < cloud->size (); i++) {
  x_cloud = cloud->points[i].x;
  y_cloud = cloud->points[i].y;
  z_cloud = cloud->points[i].z;
  msg->points.push_back (pcl::PointXYZ (x_cloud, y_cloud, z_cloud));
  }

  ros::Rate loop_rate(4);


  while (nh.ok())
  {
    //msg->header.stamp = ros::Time::now().toNSec();
    pub.publish (msg);
    ros::spinOnce ();
    loop_rate.sleep ();
  }
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273046/pcd-visualization-in-rviz-%5Bclosed%5D/) by [MT](https://answers.ros.org/users/31620/mt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-10-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-16**:
If you feel your code is the correct answer to your question (but please take a look at `pcd_to_pointcloud`), please post it as an answer yourself and accept your own answer.

**Comment by [MT](https://answers.ros.org/users/31620/mt/) on 2017-10-16**:
The goal was to perform PCL tutorials without the kinect but the PCD files given. This was the fist step of many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answer 1:

```
# include <iostream>
# include <string>

#include <ros/ros.h>

#include <pcl_ros/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
#include <pcl_ros/io/pcd_io.h>

typedef pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> PointCloud;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  double x_cloud; double y_cloud; double z_cloud;
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
  ros::init (argc, argv, "my_pcl_tutorial");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<PointCloud> ("points2", 1);
  pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZ> ("yourfile.pcd", *cloud);

  PointCloud::Ptr msg (new PointCloud);
  msg->header.frame_id = "frame1";
  msg->height = cloud->height;
  msg->width = cloud->width;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < cloud->size (); i++) {
  x_cloud = cloud->points[i].x;
  y_cloud = cloud->points[i].y;
  z_cloud = cloud->points[i].z;
  msg->points.push_back (pcl::PointXYZ (x_cloud, y_cloud, z_cloud));
  }

  ros::Rate loop_rate(4);


  while (nh.ok())
  {
    //msg->header.stamp = ros::Time::now().toNSec();
    pub.publish (msg);
    ros::spinOnce ();
    loop_rate.sleep ();
  }
}
```

Answer 2:
[pcd_to_pointcloud](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros#pcd_to_pointcloud)

---

Originally posted by [MT](https://answers.ros.org/users/31620/mt/) with karma: 31 on 2017-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ajay](https://answers.ros.org/users/35065/ajay/) on 2018-05-12**:
Thank you for the code , It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> But I can't seem to import anything and visualize successfully.

RViz visualises data *streams*, not files, so in order for you to be able to have it visualise the output of your pointcloud processing, you'll have to publish those clouds on a topic.

---

Edit (after posting your own code): if all you wanted was to publish a `.pcd` file (instead of the results of your 'manipulation' directly (ie: without going through the FS)), then the [pcd_to_pointcloud](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros#pcd_to_pointcloud) node in the [pcl_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros) package would probably have been better.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-15**:
And a bit of a nitpick: you can't really 'import' anything into RViz. It's not a visualiser like the [pcd_viewer](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/overview/visualization.php) from PCL.

**Comment by [MT](https://answers.ros.org/users/31620/mt/) on 2017-10-16**:
What exactly is FS? Just for future reference.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-16**:
The file system.